# Adding dynamic mean to time series chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I will try to explain my problem as much accurate as possible. I am looking for a javascript chart library filling the two following conditions:

```
From an ajax request retrieving time series, 
display dynamically data when changing the time window.
```

such as it is perfectly done on highstocks: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

**And**

```
plot an horizontal line corresponding to the mean, 
changing when the user update the time window on the chart.
```

Actually it is possible to display an horizontal line. But they are fixed on the whole data and do not change accordingly when the time window is modified:

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/yaxis-plotlines

I am quite new to the topic and would like to know if it'sp ossible to modify Highstock classes to have such a result. Or maybe some other `js` libraries exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a combination of the answer here:

- [Highchart, get total of visible series data after setExtremes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578322/highchart-get-total-of-visible-series-data-after-setextremes)

And an example of dynamic average using all visible series that I made for a previous question, here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/gweuLegq/

I put together this example, using the `afterSetExtremes` event, like this:

```
xAxis      : { 
            events:{
                afterSetExtremes:function() {
                    var ext = this.getExtremes();
                  getAverage(this.chart, ext.min, ext.max, show, width, avgColor, dashStyle);                
                }
            }
        },
```

Working example here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/c93543yL/

The idea is:

1) capture the afterSetExtremes event

2) get the resulting axis min and max

3) loop through the series data

4) if a point is between the min and max, increment the count, and add the 
point's y value to the sum

5) calculate the average accordingly, check for existence of average series, if exists, update, if not, add

It could as easily use a plot line that you add/remove as needed instead of a series, but I like having it as a series so that it has a legend entry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I gonna now digest it ... will keep you updated!

Comment: you're a highchart boss! I will try to adapt this to make it working with Highstock. Thanks for the help and +1 !

Comment: np. I don't work with Highstock much, but I don't think there should be much effort to make it work the same.