# HighCharts - Horizontal line with the zoomed average of the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need to display the average of the values of my 2 datasets, but with a specific characteristic: when the users zoom the chart, the average line is recalculated ONLY with the values of the zoomed area. 
How is this done?

Here is my JS:

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Test'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'Date'
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 100,
            y: 70,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 5,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                        }
                    }
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                    pointFormat: '{point.x} date, {point.y} dose'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'ag',
            color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
            data: [[1426719600000,0.9659],[1426719600000,0.8928],[1445205600000,1.6428],[1445205600000,1.4711],[1445205600000,1.4209],[1445205600000,1.9574],[1445205600000,1.1226],[1445205600000,0.8159],[1445205600000,1.0114],[1445205600000,0.9168],[1445464800000,1.175],[1445464800000,1.2219],[1445464800000,1.2641],[1445464800000,1.3006],[1445464800000,0.9375],[1445464800000,0.8966],[1445464800000,0.9374],[1445464800000,1.0811]]

        }, {
            name: 'cf',
            color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
            data: [[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.015],[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.265],[1445378400000,2.015],[1445378400000,2.015],[1445378400000,2.015],[1445464800000,1.2254],[1445464800000,1.1065],[1445464800000,1.3482],[1445464800000,1.3015],[1445292000000,1.2297]]
        }]
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The requirement is a bit unclear. I can see two values at the left side, but at the right side you have many of them. Maybe you can have a look at highcharts drilldown.

Comment: Look at my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659536/adding-dynamic-mean-to-time-series-chart/34660298#34660298

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jlbriggs but it is the first time i'm dealing with javascript and its libraries. Is it to much to ask if you can modify my JSFiddle to work properly with this characteristic?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done several ways. I am going to show you the way to do it via [`chart.events.redraw`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw). Whenever you do a zoom (or reset zoom) the chart is redrawn and this gives us a good hook into calculating and adding items to chart at that time. Here is the code block for the `redraw` event:

Here is a live **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/stmgw0t8/)**.

I made it verbose so you can see each step. We are going to use [`getExtremes()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes) to find out what are max and min `xAxis` and `yAxis` indexes are. From this we determine if the points in each series are within this "window". If they are not within the window we ignore. If they are then we add the y-value to a var and increment the point counter by 1. Once we are done we do a simple check to make sure we are not going to divide by zero and then calculate the average.

Once we have the average we then will draw a [`plotLine`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines) at the value of the average we calculated above. First we see if a plotline exists with our `id`. If it does we remove it. Then we create our new plotline.

There is some clean up to do as well (such as, do you include a 0-value plotline based on your business rules) but this should get you started.

Attempted to add code block in edit as original answer attempt would not let it through. Still unable to post code block.

Comment: Thanks a lot @wergeld !! But just one question: why plotLine only appears  when I zoom twice? I want plotLine to show always, even when the chart is loaded initially.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "twice". If you want to have it also show average plotLines on load then add a similar call in `chart.events.load`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/stmgw0t8/1/

Comment: I'm saying that plotLines don't show every time I zoom the chart. When I zoom one time they show, but when I zoom again they disappear.

Comment: @F.Rita, as I said, this code should get you started. I fixed the issue with alternating plotLines on zoom increments: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/stmgw0t8/2/

Comment: Thanks for your kindness @wergeld . I've added another features that I wanted and it seems to work properly :) I'm not that good with JS, it is a new programe language for me that's why I am trying to understand it with someone that is a master in this.

Comment: just one more question @wergeld: I have a 3rd dataset that has 100 000 points and the chart becames to slow in navigation. Do you know how the dataGrouping feature works? Or another way to solve this? I've been reading about this and realized that it applies only on StockCharts. I don't care if my chart becomes a stockchart, but I can't make this work properly. Do you know how to do this? Thanks again.

Comment: @F.Rita, you can do `dataGrouping` on a scatter series (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.scatter.dataGrouping). I would also take a look at removing drop shadows and animations and other items that are "for show" but don't enhance data viz. You need to use hightstock for dataGrouping.

Comment: i've made additional changes in the jsfiddle so it can also calculate the 90th percentile but I'm getting bugs, e.g, the average and the 90th percentile are wrong calculated and the zoom selector is still on after I zoom. Can you take a look at this please? Don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stmgw0t8/4/

Comment: @F.Rita, take a look at your console. You have errors in your fiddle. This would probably be best asked as a new question.